# Redirect (rewrite?) subfolders to parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've moved all my PDF files from several subfolders to the parent folder /downloads/
Examples old situation:

```
https://www.example.com/downloads/2011/subfolder2/subfolder3/file1.pdf
https://www.example.com/downloads/2011/subfolder4/subfolder5/subfolder6/file2.pdf
https://www.example.com/downloads/2011/subfolder7/file3.pdf
https://www.example.com/downloads/2011/subfolder7/file4.pdf
```

So it was all about PDF files in different subfolders in /downloads/2011/

And now it's like this (there are many more files):

```
https://www.example.com/downloads/file1.pdf
https://www.example.com/downloads/file2.pdf
https://www.example.com/downloads/file3.pdf
https://www.example.com/downloads/file4.pdf
```

I'd like to redirect the old links in the search engines to the new.
So in fact all subfolders (except downloads) should be removed from the old url's
or
all old links to all PDF's on the site, wherever they were, should be redirected to the downloads folders.

How should I do any of these possibilities with .htaccess?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Hi, thank you.
Among other things I tried:

    RedirectMatch 301 ^/downloads/$ http://example.com/downloads

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(downloads/). /$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^downloads\/.+\/(.+)$ downloads/$1 [R=301]
```

That should do the trick already.

There appears to be no need to be more specific with the first `.+` match, or use character classes that exclude the slash; the greediness of regular expressions works in our favor here.

Comment: Tanks for your answer.
This gives a 403 Forbidden error. It looks like it redirects to the downloads folder, not to the file(s) in it.

Comment: Can you try with the pattern `^downloads\/.+\/([^\\]+)$`, and see if that works? Explicitly demanding the last part to _not_ contain a slash might be necessary after all, instead of relying on greediness alone.

Comment: Initially the first and second solution did work only for some links only (tried several browser with cleared cache) but suddenly both solutions did work for all files!
I can't see any difference in the structure of the links that did work and that didn't. But anyhow, it works now.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: (I had the slash the wrong way around in the pattern suggested in that comment, it needs to be a forward slash, not a backslash. But if the original suggestion also works already, not much point in extended attempts to correct it now.)

Comment: Yes, I already did change that second backslash.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/downloads/.+/([^/.]+)\.pdf$ /downloads/$1.pdf
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a different browser to test the redirection.